# Javascript variable scope - are the two connections the same?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm trying to understand something, When I try to compare the 2 `connection` variables, it seems like they are not the same.
Could someone explain if the two are the same connections? (in the comments LINE 3 and LINE 10)

```
router.get('/admin/some_api', function (req, res, next) {

pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) { //LINE 3

    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream('some_file.txt')
    });

    lineReader.on('line', function (fileLine) {
            loadData(connection, currentDomain, function (dataSet) { // LINE 10
            ....
```

I was told that "the context is not the same" in line 3 and 10, therefore this is not the same reference. Is it true?

Comment: How are you comparing them?  They should indeed be the same.  Note that if `connection` is a reference to an object, "same" means it's the same reference, not that the object being pointed to is unchanged at the two points in time.  If there's anything asynchronous going on (like `lineReader.on` perhaps?) then something else could be changing/updating whatever `connection` is externally.

Comment: You only have one `connection` (which is a parameter, not a variable, but in JavaScript the distinction is quite minor). Unless there's code you haven't shown, it definitely has the same value upon the entry to the `getConnection` callback as it has on line 10.

Comment: Sorry, when I say "the same" I mean the same object reference, not values of course.

Comment: Technically, yes - "the context is not the same" is true.  However, since `connection` is not defined in the inner context(s), it will continue looking up the chain until it finds it.